# Why does my spread operator show this behaviour?

Tags: javascript

```
let schools = [
{ name: "Yorktown"},
{ name: "Stratford" },
{ name: "Washington & Lee"},
{ name: "Wakefield"}
]

let updatedSchools = editName("Stratford", "HB Woodlawn", schools)
console.log( updatedSchools[1] ) // { name: "HB Woodlawn" }


    const editName = (oldName, name, arr) =>
      arr.map(item => {
        if (item.name === oldName) {
          // what is happening below!?
          return {
            ...item,
            name
          }
        } else {
          return item
        }
      })
```

first of all, i'm sorry if this question might be easy for you, but i'm having trouble understanding how the return statement of the snippet works and would really appreciate help.

```
return { ...item, name }
```

So i would expect `updatedSchool` to be (even though it's invalid syntax):

```
[
  {name: "Yorktown"},
  { name: "Yorktown", "HB Woodlawn"},  
  { name: "Washington & Lee"},  
  { name: "Wakefield"}  
]
```

why does it produce `{ name: "HB Woodlawn" }`?

Comment: Arrays start with id 0 as the first entry, in most programming languages

Comment: Why does the second item include `"HB Woodlawn"` *and* `"Yorktown"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply desugar expression step by step

```
{...item, name }
```

First `{name}` is shortcut for `{name: name}`

Then `{...obj}` is the same as `Object.assign({}, obj)`

Combining both gives `Object.assign({}, obj, {name: name})`

Given `obj = {name: 'Stratford'}` has only one property `name` it will simply create new object and replace name with a new one.

You can read about `Object.assign` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: Interesting stuff going on :o. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. By the way you could use babeljs.io repl to make this desugaring for you. https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=false&lineWrap=false&presets=env%2Cstage-0&targets=&browsers=last%202%20versions&builtIns=true&debug=false&code=const%20obj%20%3D%20%7Bname%3A%20'test'%7D%2C%0A%20%20newObj%20%3D%20%7B...obj%2C%20name%7D

Answer (score 1):

```js
return {    // the spread operator assigns existing properties of item
  ...item,  // to the new returned object
  name      // similar to return Object.assign(item, {name: name})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The rest parameter can work on objects as well as arrays in browsers that support it.  If you want to understand the code, it's best to walk through it.

`editSchools` is a function that takes an `oldName`, a `name`, and an `array`.  It returns the result of the mapping from `array` to a new array.  Each element in the new array is determined by the callback function that `map` executes.  If the `item`'s `name` property is equal to the `oldName`, then a new object is created which will take its place, `{...item, name}`.  This is where the confusion lies.

It does something weird. The new object recieves all the keys of the `item` object, and then it will define (or redefine) the `name` property to the value of `name` provided to `editSchools`.

So in essence, this code finds the objects that have a `name` key whose value is `oldName` and replaces it with an identical new object with a changed `name` property to the new `name` value.